# is mysql inner join and substring combination possible?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, sql-like

here's my current query, but i want to select items under member.memberOffices that matches a substring.

```
SELECT 
w1115.idNumber, 
w1115.id, 
members.firstName, 
members.lastName, 
members.memberOffices, 
members.idNumber 
FROM w1115 
INNER JOIN members ON w1115.idNumber=members.idNumber WHERE mode='F9'
```

Comment: Yes possible  but you need to provide some sample data.

Comment: And try to ident that query to improve readability pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is mysql inner join and substring combination possible?

We actually have no idea what is the desired result set, but yes it is possible.

```
INNER JOIN members ON w1115.idNumber=members.idNumber WHERE mode='F9'
```

Note that if `mode` exist in multiple tables, you need to specify the proper alias else it will give you an error.

I am also not sure what you mean by *substring combination*, but I don't see any substring in your join.

Have a look at [this mini-tutorial](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php) on how do use `substring`.

Answer (score 0):

sorry if my question is vague. here's what i was trying to achieve where '0' is a substring in memberOffices column

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT w1115.idNumber, w1115.id, members.firstName, members.lastName, members.memberOffices
               FROM w1115 INNER JOIN members ON w1115.idNumber=members.idNumber WHERE mode='F9') 
as AA WHERE memberOffices LIKE '%0%'
```